# Sorting DIVs with an already sorted array

Tags: jquery

I'm new here and new to Javascript and web programming (I actually know a little bit of Java not for web). So here's the problem I have an array of strings (name of Albums to be more specific) and I actually sorted this array according to the Album names.
Now that I have this array sorted my next step would be sort the DIVs that represent each Album, but I actually don't know how to do it with JQuery.
Here's how my DIVs are distribuited in the page:

```
<div id="products" >
   <div class="line">
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div id="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to sort all the DIVs with id="product-Album-name".
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: IDs must be unique. How your divs should be sorted and what have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you want to sort them? THere are no differences in your example, so you can't sort them.

Answer (score 1):

I have re-created a scenario in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgeYq/1/) http://jsfiddle.net/sgeYq/1/. It uses jQuery and your pre-sorted album list and creates your `<div id='{alnumname}'>albumname</div>` sections grouped by 4 albums in each `<div class='line'>...</div>` section. You can modify the `index % 4` in order change amount in groups.

Comment: That's actually what I wanted thank you so much alexi, but there's some more information I didn't tell. I use the Liquid for designers "language" in my web site and it is actually usefull in some ways, I could make the pagination and I could actually insert the div dynamically with class="line" with 4 or 5 products inside only using the Liquid "language". So if I use your code, I would have to make the pagination using Javascript too right?Ay suggestions? 

here's my page: biscoitofino.jumpseller.com/catalogo

Comment: @Leo, it is not an easy question. You may do and you may not as well. It depends on how you approach this. You don't need to change the pagination, if you can retrieve your album lists as a JSON object using some REST calls, lets say, `http://biscoitofino.jumpseller.com/catalogoJSON?page=2` which will retrieve a sorted array of albums, then using jQuery and AJAX you can retrieve list and slightly modify the code I wrote in above to update UI. In this case, when you click page links, list on UI will be updated dynamically, without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Alexis so let's suppose that the DIVs already exist (even the Line DIVs), like this:http://jsfiddle.net/sgeYq/2/
What should I do to sort them this way? I know there's a way to clone a DIV with its content and change its position but I have no idea how to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Leo, please see [http://jsfiddle.net/sgeYq/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/sgeYq/5/). I have updated the code to use the existing list of the divs. Hope this script helps. In this example, the ID's are sorted ALPHABETICALLY, so don't be confused when you see, `album1, album10, album11 etc.`. For sorting DIV that has only NUMERIC id's, I have put there additional commented line with comment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

First thing I see that your element id is not unique.. According to HTML standards the id's should be unique in your document.. Why don't you use classes instead.

```
<div class="products" >
   <div class="line">
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="line">
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
      <div class="product-Album-name"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also as all the div's are the same how can it be sorted if there is no noticeable difference

Comment: I just presumed that the OP was using that as a stand in. I'm presuming they will be unique... with the ID of the album

Comment: I recognize that this "answer" is too long to be a comment, but it's really a comment. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes exactly that was just an example the IDs are unique and are specific according to the Album